# wordpress qtranslate language switch install

Tags: css, wordpress

I have wordpress site http://highlander.ge and installed avada theme.
Problem is in qTranslate language bar.
I would like to add it to sticky meny, but didn't succeeded. I added code  to the appropriate header file.

Now the task is to remove bullets from css but didn't succeeded - just can't find where is css code generated by qtranslate...

can anyone help with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove bullet points by adding this CSS line:

```
.qtrans_language_chooser { list-style-type:none }
```